Undefined variable error in flutter web index.html file
So I am loading a webview in flutter web app using webview_flutter_web. Problem is that when Flutter loads the webview, the variables in index.html giving me undefined error when I console them in chrome inspect section. Following is the sample code of index.html file.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
    <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF" />

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project." />

    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="webtesting" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png" />

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

    <title>webtesting</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />

    <script>
      // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
      const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    </script>
    <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
    <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var hello = "init";
      console.log(hello);
      window.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {
        // Download main.dart.js
        _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          serviceWorker: {
            serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          },
          onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
            engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function (appRunner) {
              appRunner.runApp();
              hello = "init 2";
              console.log(hello);
            });
          },
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



You can see I defined variable name in the body section (I also tried to define this variable in head section also in separate script but didn't work) var hello = "init"; The console.log is working fine when it is loading and also consoling the value of hello. But when I am consoling it to chrome inspect section it is giving me  error. Strange behaviour is that if I reload the page then it is working fine. My concern is that why it is not console the value initially first time.
Following is my flutter code to load the webview.
class _WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const _WebViewExample();

  @override
  _WebViewExampleState createState() => _WebViewExampleState();
}

class _WebViewExampleState extends State<_WebViewExample> {
  final PlatformWebViewController _controller = PlatformWebViewController(
    const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams(),
  )..loadRequest(
      LoadRequestParams(
        uri: Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'),
      ),
    );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
      ),
      body: PlatformWebViewWidget(
        PlatformWebViewWidgetCreationParams(controller: _controller),
      ).build(context),
    );
  }
}

